# Change group permission level

Tags: permissions

How can I change a group permission level? In `Site > Site Settings > My group` I can see all the members. Add and remove members is possible. In `Settings > Show Group's authorization` I can see (but not modify) that the level is "Collaboration". How to change this?

**NOTE**: Sharepoint is in Italian, so the labels I used may not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Site Settings, there will be a link called Advanced Permissions.  Clicking on that link will allow you to modify the permission level for the group.  If you don't see this link, then you might not have the ability to modify permissions in the site.

Comment: Five years down the line, I think @contactmatt's answer is a better 'best answer' to the question than this one.

Comment: user1792252's answer would be technically better as it is platform version agnostic. This question was asked in 2011, so a 2013 based answer wouldn't have been applicable.

Comment: in agreement on both counts.

Answer (score 12):

1.Select Site Actions > Site Permissions
2.Check the box next to the person or group you want to modify
3.Select the Edit User Permissions button

Answer (score 8):

In SharePoint 2013, go to:

Site Settings -> Site Permissions. Then select the group you want to edit via the checkbox, and click *Edit User Permissions*.

Comment: Thanks @contactmatt. This answer got me through and allowed me to complete my objective, as explained in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;     

namespace SampleApplication1    
{    
    class Program    
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)    
        {    
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://rohit:34143/"))    
            {    
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)    
                {    
                    SPRoleDefinitionCollection roleColl = web.RoleDefinitions;

                    foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in roleColl)    
                    {    
                        Console.WriteLine(role.Name.ToString());    
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();    
                }    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

For more details on how to getting the permission level in sharepoint 2010 using c#:

[Getting the permission levels from SharePoint 2010 using C#](http://mindstick.com/Articles/06e20e89-d95f-45a2-b3cd-7fd011ed8738/?Getting%20the%20permission%20levels%20from%20SharePoint%202010%20using%20C#)

Comment: While there is definitely a place for C# code, managing basic permissions is not.